# Automatically Marquee Code scrolling with recent post title?

Tags: html

I want Automatically Marquee Code scrolling with recent post title in Header. any one can tell me. my marquee code

```
<div id="breakingNews1"><img src="http://news1.techjagot.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/2013-06-09_203855.png"/><FONT SIZE="4" FACE="TT" COLOR=green><marquee width="820">any text here </marquee></FONT> </div>
```

how i can do i. anyone can tell me? my site http://news1.techjagot.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I told you in chat, you just need the recent posts and can add any markup you need:

```
// functions.php
function recent_inaccessible_posts()
{
    if ( ! $recent = wp_get_recent_posts(array(), OBJECT ) )
        return;

    $out = '<marquee><ul>';
    foreach ( $recent as $r )
        $out .= '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($r->ID) . '">' . get_the_title($r->ID) . '</a>';

    print "$out</ul></marquee>";
}
```

Call it wherever you need it with `recent_inaccessible_posts();`.

Be aware, scrolling text is almost inaccessible for many users. I would never use it.